# Borders of text boxes not getting painted after validation fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am just following a `ASP.NET MVC` book example and for validation we have added those `[Required]` attributes to the model and it works but now it has added a style sheet to highlight the fields that have issues as well.
Here is how it looks in my IE:

[image]

Notice the "red" style is being applied but the borders are not red, and this is how the book screen shot says it should look like:

[image]

and here is the `CSS` I have just copied from the book, so why mine doesn't make the text box border red?

```
.field-validation-error    {color: #f00;}
.field-validation-valid    { display: none;}
.input-validation-error    { border: 1px solid #f00; background-color: #fee; }
.validation-summary-errors { font-weight: bold; color: #f00;}
.validation-summary-valid  { display: none;}
```

Comment: is it only problem in IE or u have tested with chrome and FF as well?

Comment: in the browser - while the form is invalid , right click the textbox and click "Inspect Element" - can you tell us what classes are assigned to the *invalid* textbox ?

Answer (score 1):

For client side validation use jquery and jquery validation. Also enabled client side validation from the web.config:

```
add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"
```

** Also ensure your styles are being applied using the IE developer toolbar.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  The `[required]` attribute that the OP refers to is a C# attribute, having nothing to do with the browser or its tags.

Comment: It seems none of your styles are being applied. Could you confirm this using your IE developer toolbar? Please select an input control and check if "input-validation-error" style has been applied during an invalid form?